# Localhost Cookie domain

Tags: spring, http, cookies, cross-origin-read-blocking

I am working on a Java Spring MVC application that authenticates a user with CAS and then generates a JWT. That token is added to a cookie and then the user is redirected to another application running locally. The url for the Spring Application is `http://localhost:8080/Authentication/`. The other application the user is redirected to is at `http://localhost:52554/`. My question is why isn't the cookie available at `http://localhost:52554/`? Since both applications are running in local host they are running on the same domain. I verified that the token cookie is set for `http://localhost:8080/Authentication/`. Upon redirect to `http://localhost:52554/`, the cookie is gone.  Any help is appreciated here.